# Conditional expectation of discrete random variable given noisy observation

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have discrete random variable given by
\begin{align*}
P(X=x_i)=\frac{1}{N},  i=1...N
\end{align*}
and Gaussian r.v. $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Assume $Z$ and $X$ are independent.
Suppose $X$ and $Z$ form an new r.v. $Y$ give by
\begin{align*}
Y=X+Z
\end{align*}

I am interested in computing $E[X|Y]$?

Here are some of the distributions that I have computed:
\begin{align*}
f_Y(y)&=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(y-x_i)^2/2}\\
f_{Y|X}(y|x_i)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(y-x_i)^2/2}=f_Z(z)\\
f_{X|Y}(x_i|y)&=???
\end{align*}

But I am not sure how to proceed next. For example does density $f_{X|Y}(x_i|y)$ even exists?
Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{N\sqrt{2\pi}}\;e^{-(y-x)^2/2}.$$

Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{X|Y}(x|y) &=& \dfrac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{\frac{1}{N\sqrt{2\pi}}\;e^{-(y-x)^2/2}}{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(y-x_i)^2/2}} \\
&& \\
&=& \dfrac{e^{-(y-x)^2/2}}{\sum_{i=1}^N e^{-(y-x_i)^2/2}}\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{for $x\in\{x_1,\ldots,x_N\},\; y\in\mathbb{R}$.} \\
&& \\
\therefore \quad E(X\mid Y) &=& \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i e^{-(y-x_i)^2/2}}{\sum_{i=1}^N e^{-(y-x_i)^2/2}}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}